# Traducción sencilla y elegante para "one hit wonder"

Tags: traducción

Un [**one hit wonder**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hit_wonder) es un grupo o cantante que es famoso por una única canción muy exitosa, mientras que el resto de su discografía pasa prácticamente desapercibido. Algunos ejemplos serían ["*Breakfast at Tiffany's*"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast_at_Tiffany's_(song)) de Deep Blue Something, "La Macarena" de Los del Río, o incluso el [*canon de Pachelbel*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Af372EQLck) (parece ser que a pesar del éxito de Johann Pachelbel en su día hoy sólo se le conoce por el canon que lleva su nombre).

El término *one hit wonder* es traducido en [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=one+hit+wonder) como

> estrella efímera de un único éxito resonante

y en [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hit_wonder) como

> maravilla de un solo éxito; artista que generalmente es conocido por un solo sencillo exitoso

Parece ser que la definición del término es más o menos restrictiva, dependiendo de si nos queremos referir a artistas que tienen una canción dentro de un determinado ranking (UK Singles Chart, Billboard Hot 100,...) o que son sólo conocidos por tener un único exitazo musical en toda su carrera, pero la acepción más popular es la de "artista(s) famoso(s) por un *único* exitazo".

En español, hasta donde yo sé, nadie usa "estrella efímera de un único éxito" o "maravilla de un solo éxito" o "artista sólo conocido un un único sencillo exitoso". Esos términos suenan un poco rebuscados o incluso pedantes, más explicativos que descriptivos.

Cuál puede ser un término sencillo y elegante en español para traducir *"one hit wonder"*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Flor de un día" se utiliza habitualmente para referirse a éxitos efímeros que no se repiten, al menos en España.

Comment: Buen aporte. Quizá el sentido de "flor de un día" es más amplio que "one hit wonder" (por ejemplo, cualquiera de los famosillos de la casa de Gran Hermano, el último ligue de X o de Y famosos, un actor muy encasillado en un papel...), pero es cierto que se usa con ese sentido "el cantante que triunfó con la canción del verano y nunca más se supo de él"

Answer (score 5):

Parece difícil. No consigo nada más breve que lo siguiente:

```
Estrella de un solo éxito
```

Tiene ya algunas ocurrencias en Internet:

> *Estrellas de un solo éxito: ¿cuál es tu one-hit wonder favorito?* (http://www.rtve.es/noticias/20111118/estrellas-solo-exito-cual-tu-one-hit-wonder-favorito/476306.shtml)
>
> *20 'one hit wonders': estrellas de un solo éxito* (http://elcomercio.pe/luces/musica/20-one-hit-wonders-estrellas-solo-exito-noticia-1751545)
>
> *[...] arreglaban, interpretaban y producían discos muy influyentes de música disco y R&B, tanto para artistas ya establecidos, como para estrellas de un sólo éxito, como [...]* (http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chic)

PS: me he tomado la libertad de corregir eso de "**maravilla** de un solo éxito" en la entrada de la Wikipedia de "One hit wonder", "**estrella**" parece mucho más apropiado que "maravilla".

Comment: "Estrella de un solo éxito" desde luego me convence más que "maravilla de un sólo éxito". No es mala idea. Es curioso que de los tres links que aportas dos usan también la expresión en inglés, y es más interesante todavía que uno es de RTVE... Dentro del artículo se refiere a ellos como "esos artistas que alcanzaron un éxito masivo una única vez".

Answer (score 0):

En México, "llamarada de petate" se usa para lo mismo. El petate se consume rápidamente, entonces la llama que crea es de muy corta duración.

Comment: Cierto que la expresión tiene ese significado, pero parece ser un coloquialismo de México (ya que allí significa "tejido de palma"). "Petate" tiene otro sentido en otros países (equipaje), y [algunas fuentes](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=llamarada+de+petate) lo asocian más a un sentimiento efímero o entusiasmo sorpresivo que a la condición que describe "one hit wonder".

Comment: Apart from a literal translation based on a definition of "one hit wonder" there is also a common understanding that many of these songs are just plain stupid.  Some of which the listener never wishes to hear again.  For that, I don't know a simple translation other than "A Dumb Song"

Comment: @JohnPeters I don't think so. Some classics where written and/or performed by one-hit wonders.